# Compare the lines of code in TFS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way i can get a report from TFS which compares the number of lines of code that has been changed based on the last checked in version of the project ?
I am able to get the number of lines of code by using the code metrics for the current project but i am unable to find an option where i can compare the lines of code that has been changed.

I would appreciate if some who has performed such thing earlier would guide me to the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to display the CodeChurn statistic on a ChangeSet basis.

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244661.aspx) on the MSDN, especially in the "Dimension and Attributes in the Code Churn Perspective That Support Filtering and Categorization" section to filter the data for a given ChangeSet.

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jampick/archive/2010/07/06/tfs-2010-code-churn-report-getting-additional-detail.aspx) may also be helpful.